# Python regular expression sub

Tags: python, regex, substitution

So I am running into something I cant explain and was hoping someone could shed light on... Here is my code:

```
fd = open(inFile, 'r')
contents = fd1.readlines()
fd.close()
contentsOrig = contents
contents[3] = re.sub(replaceRegex, thingToReplaceWith, contentsOrig[3])
```

Now when I print out contents and contentsOrig they are exactly the same. I was trying to preserve what I originally read in but from this little code it doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone enlighten me?

I am running Python 2.7.7

Answer (score 0):

In Python, mutable objects cannot be copied the way you are copying them. If effect, doing `x = y` only sets x and y to the same address in memory - they reference the same object (in this case a list). If you use the ID function `id(x)` and `id(y)` they will actually be the same!
Edit: note that the poster below showed `x is y`; the is keyword is using the id function in the background.

A simpler example is here:

```
list_one = [1, 2, 3]
list_two = list_one
list_one.append(4)
print list_one        #will show [1, 2, 3, 4], as expected
print list_two        #will ALSO show [1, 2, 3, 4]!
```

In this case, to get around this problem you can use list splicing to make the new list:

```
new_list = original_list[:]
```

If you have multiple nested lists (or other mutable objects), then you can use the deepcopy module to make a copy, if you want all the nested lists to be copied as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you assign a list to another variable, it's not a copy of that list, it is a reference. Meaning there is still one copy of that list and now both variables point to it.

```
contentsOrig = contents
contentsOrig is contents
# Result: True
```

When you change one of the values or modify the list in any it is changing the same list. So what you need to do is make a copy of the list. This is done by either of these ways:

```
contentsOrig = contents[:]
```

or

```
contentsOrig = list(contents)
```

The first way is using the list slicing to produce a new list from the beginning to the end. The second takes a list and returns a new copy of the list.

Note that both ways do not make new copies of the items inside the list. So it's the same items, but different containers. But since these are strings, they are not mutable and therefore if modified inside a list, the original string will be untouched in the the original list.